# Accurate USB GPS Unit

Tags: usb, gps

This afternoon I tested an AmbiCom USB GPS and the cordinates were jumping all over. Most of them were at least 30 feet off. Anyone have any experience with any other brands/have any recommendations for a more accurate USB GPS unit?

Comment: That's called "Jitter" (IIRC) and 30 feet (10 meters) is about as accurate as consumer level devices get...

Comment: if you want significantly better accuracy, join (or possibly contract for) the US military.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accuracy of GPS depends on many factors:

- the consumer accuracy (15 to 30 ft approx.), due to jam in consumer signals (the military accuracy is far better)
- the number of satellites in view (3 is the bare minimum)
- the environment (near building or structure, reflection and refraction of materials)

So don't expect a better accuracy.

Comment: [Nowadays, is there any way to track the movements of my vehicle with GPS precisely?](https://superuser.com/questions/1723070/gps-tracking-precisely)

Answer (score 1):

A very quick read of the specs for the device indicates that GPS accuracy is 16 to 33 ft **Approximately**.  What you have observed is exactly how the device works or for that matter most GPS devices.